# How to include images from angular2 webpack assets

Tags: image, angular, webpack

I build a angular2 webpack app.

put a image in the **'src/assets/images/default.png'**

and in **webpack.common.js**:

```
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
            from: 'src/assets',
            to: 'assets'
          }]),

 { test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/, loader: 'file' },

new AssetsPlugin({
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        filename: 'webpack-assets.json',
        prettyPrint: true
      }),
```

when i include in template like this :

```
    <img  [src]="path" width="160" height="200" />

this.path='assets/images/default.png';
```

the image not loaded .

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using file-loader (npm install file-loader --save-dev) ...

in webpack.common.js

```
module: {
    loaders: [

        ...

        {
            test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
            loaders: ['file-loader?name=assets/[name].[hash].[ext]']
        },

        ...
    ]
}
```

This still does not make background in "style=" attributes work however, which is probably a good thing for best practice.